# Detecting Ruby typos in VIM

Tags: ruby, vim

I write tests and I use guard but my issue is: I don't want to wait for guard to run my test case to figure out that I am using a variable that hasn't been 'declared' due to a typo.

The question is, is there a VIM plugin that can warn is such instances?

```
:w !ruby -c
```

returns syntax ok for

```
def foo
  return far
end
```

It would be great if I could see a warning that, at least within my current file, `far` is neither a method, an argument or assigned in the scope I'm in.

Suggestions or pointers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you use [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) ? It does a great job showing you what variables you've defined that are not in use.

Comment: I do use syntastic but it doesn't seem to show the variables that are potentially "undeclared" and are not methods either

Answer (score 0):

Not sure undeclared variable can be caught, but many other syntax errors can be caught using [vim-rubocop](https://github.com/ngmy/vim-rubocop).

Comment: Thanks, will give a shot to see if I get warned about "undeclared" variables =)